# Reference request: 2-Grothendieck Construction

Tags: grothendieck-construction, ct.category-theory

Hi Folks,

i'm looking for a reference on the 2-grothendieck construction for a functor $F:\mathcal{I}\to \mathcal{B}\mathrm{icat}$ from a bicategory $\mathcal{I}$ to the tricategory of bicategories. Actually for my purposes it would be sufficient to consider functors going only to $\mathcal{C}\mathrm{at}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I. Bakovic, [Grothendieck construction for bicategories](http://www.irb.hr/users/ibakovic/sgc.pdf).

Comment: Thank you; This is exactly the article i was looking for.

Comment: Quoted is a very old version of Igor's manuscript, from 2009 or so. Igor had written in the meantime several much longer and more detailed manuscripts on the subject; hopefully he will be soon happy enough with them to post to the arXiv. There are also available slides from his Cambridge talk on a related topic of fibrations within tricategories <https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~jg352/pdf/pssl93talks/PSSL93Bakovic.pdf>. Igor this December gave a talk on the present state of the subject at Paris VII. 